# Other than by wrapping each character with an html element, is there a way in javascript/jquery/etc to tell which letter in an element was clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*Other than* by wrapping each character with an html element, is there a way in javascript/jquery/etc to tell which letter in an element was clicked on?

Say you've got a heading -- `"<h1>Happy</h1>"` -- how can you tell which letter was clicked on, i.e., the user clicked on the second p or the a --without tag-wrapping each letter.

All the solutions that I've found suggest wrapping each letter in an html element (presumably a span), but that requires some pretty horrific html (even if you automate generating it) -- i.e., `<h1><span id="letter00>H</span><span id="letter02">a</span><span id=letter03>p</p>...etc...</h1>`.  Surely there is someway to record letter positions as the rendering engine is drawing them and then relating those to clicks in the viewport.

Comment: well you would not really need the id on the spans around each character

Comment: If you are working with contenteditable, there is a way to do it with cursor position, but I am guessing it is not.

Comment: Why would you need that?  Surely there is something wrong where you need to bind specific events to specific letters

Comment: Look at the properties of a [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent). From that you could get the x and y positions. Translating that to the character you clicked on would be difficult, but not impossible.

Comment: Your best bet may be something like this: https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/wiki/Wrapping-letters-with-lettering() It still wraps using elements, but at least you don't have the burden of doing it yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927065/determining-a-character-of-a-sentence-when-clicked-on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining a character of a sentence when clicked on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927065/determining-a-character-of-a-sentence-when-clicked-on)

Comment: @Pete, @Mike McCaughan,  What I'd like to do is enable a user to "overmark" a webpage, for instance, highlighting particular passages within a heading or paragraph.  -- preferably then being able to "edit" the html to add something like `<span style="background-color: yellow"></span>`  in the html so the user could see his marks later.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you used an `<input type="text">`  you have a selectionStart property which contains the character index of where your cursor is at.  With html you can modify the textbox to remove the border and such so it doesnt look like a textbox.  selectionStart and selectionEnd will help you figure out if any of the text is highlighted as well.

Comment: What I'd like to do is enable a user to "overmark" a webpage, for instance, highlighting particular passages within a heading or paragraph.

Comment: I am pretty sure this will give you that ability. those selection properties provide you with the cursor locations and what characters are currently selected or highlighted.  You will have to write some javascript to be able to grab those characters but its definitely doable.