# Detect which letter from a word is clicked using javascript

Tags: javascript

I notice different solutions on the internet where is described how to detect the `word` where the user clicked. But i want to know if there is a solution to detect the letter from a word or the position where the user clicks. Ex:

```html
<div>this is the text</div>
```

When the user clicks on the first letter in the console should be outputted `t`. 
 Is a solution to find the clicked letter like i described above using javascript?

Comment: Unless you want to give each individual letter an onclick, I suspect the answer is no. There is a similar question asked about jquery that you might want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927065/determining-a-character-of-a-sentence-when-clicked-on

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) to check where the cursor is and extract the closest letter to it:

```js
document.onclick = (evt) => {
  const sel = getSelection();
  if (sel.rangeCount) {
    const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    const targetedNode = range.startContainer;
    const clickedLetter = targetedNode.textContent.substr(range.startOffset, 1);
    console.log(clickedLetter);
  }
};
```

```html
<div>this is the text</div>
```

But it may very well fail in a lot of corner-cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Selection.focusOffset` to get position of character which is nearest to cursor click focus.

```js
document.onclick = (event) => {
  const selection = getSelection();
  const charClicked = selection.focusNode.data[selection.focusOffset]
  if (charClicked) {
    console.log(charClicked);
  }
};
```

```html
<div>this is the text</div>
```